# how do you write the code for mybind

Tags: javascript

I found this code in a book, how do you write or define the code for **mybind**

```
var concat = function(a, b) { return a + " " + b;}
var good = mybind(concat, "good");
good("night") == "good night"
```

Comment: `function mybind(arg1, arg2) { ... }`

Comment: I meant the hard code for it :D the logic

Comment: @ratebaltal What is `mybind` supposed to do? What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: I think it is supossed to bind good  to the concat function, I tried this :
function mybind(func,v){
    
    func.bind(v);
    return func(v);
}

Comment: @ratebaltal you are close.  bind returns a new function though, so you just need to return the result of calling bind.  Also the first argument to bind is an object that is to be bound to `this`, so you need to pass that argument as well.  like `function( fn, b ) { return fn.bind(this, b); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will make your comparison return true.  `myBind` should create a new function bound to `b`.  that's what `bind` does.

```
var mybind = function( fn, b ) { return fn.bind(this, b); };
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new function, you can either create it yourself:

```js
function mybind(f, a) {
  return function (b) {
    return f(a, b);
  }
}

var concat = function(a, b) { return a + " " + b;}
var good = mybind(concat, "good");
console.log(good("night"));
```

or for your scenario you can use [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create one for you

```js
function mybind(f, a) {
  return f.bind(null, a);
}

var concat = function(a, b) { return a + " " + b;}
var good = mybind(concat, "good");
console.log(good("night"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
var concat = function(a, b) { return a + " " + b;}
var mybind = function (fn, arg1) {
  return function (arg2) {
    return fn(arg1, arg2);
  };
}
var good = mybind(concat, "good");
console.log(good("night") === "good night")
```